# Issues with iwlwifi drivers on fresh 20.04 install

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi, firmware

I recently got a Thinkpad P14s, since I saw it was Ubuntu Certified hardware. Install of 20.04 went fine, but I do not seem to have a wifi option in network settings. Following some other posts I have seen, I am posting output of certain commands below.

```
$ uname -a
Linux osprey 5.8.0-53-generic #60~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 09:52:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0020]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   17.278197] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   17.287578] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.287958] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288243] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288254] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288263] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288272] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288281] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288291] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288300] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288310] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288321] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288330] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288340] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288350] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288360] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288372] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288783] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288793] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.288795] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[   17.288797] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-39
[   17.288798] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56
[   17.288799] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Running `ls /lib/firmware | grep iwlwifi-ty` returns `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode`, so it seems to me like I have an unsupported version. How do I go about getting a supported version?

Comment: It sounds like this is an AX210 card.  You can only get AX210 card support in iwlwifi in 21.04 or newer, becuase it's part of the 5.10+ Kernel, and not the older kernel in Ubuntu 20.04.  You have to read the hardware certifications to actually make sure the card *tested* is the card that got 'certified'.  AX210 only works in 21.04.  You might want to wait for the next 20.04 point release for the next HWE kernel so that you have the updated kernel and iwlwifi support.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: A fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 gave me kernel 5.10.0.
And I had no wifi detected.
This solved my problem:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update