# Ubuntu 20.04 on a ThinkPad T14 gen 2 - No wifi detected

Tags: wireless, internet, thinkpad, interface

I tried in a first place to install Manjaro on my new computer, unfortunately I was not able to connect it in Ethernet or Wifi. At this moment, I thought that Manjaro was broken so I decided to move on Ubuntu (more stable) and again I got no Wifi, but this time I can use Ethernet. I figure out that I have no Wireless Interface:

```
$ lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:bc300000-bc303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 20
       serial: 38:f3:ab:5d:a8:98
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-3 ip=192.168.1.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:147 memory:bcf00000-bcf1ffff
```

```
$ lspci | grep -i net

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V (rev 20)
09:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
```

I also download the driver from the Intel website:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html
for the Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz and move all the drivers to /lib/firmware but it is still not working..

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
9:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0020]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0a:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Genesys Logic, Inc GL9750 SD Host Controller [17a0:9750] (rev 01)
```

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.099407] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.109641] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110148] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110171] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110371] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110457] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110471] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110594] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110606] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110617] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110629] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110641] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110652] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110663] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110673] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110702] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110712] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110721] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110731] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.110732] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    3.110734] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-39
[    3.110735] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56
[    3.110736] iwlwifi 0000:09:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Thanks for your help and sorry if I'm not using this site quite well I'm new :)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It is updated, thanks for helping !

Comment: Please see the comment here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338070/issues-with-iwlwifi-drivers-on-fresh-20-04-install I suggest that you reinstall Ubuntu 21.04 and your wireless should be working perfectly.

Comment: okay thank you I will test that