# Intel Wifi 6 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, iwlwifi

After the latest updates (Terminal: `sudo apt update & upgrade`) my WiFi suddenly didn't work anymore.
I did a fresh installation including all applications necessary for me and again did not work after the updates.

Yesterday I reproduced it after a fresh installation (20.04 LTS - latest version) WiFi is working until I do updates.

System: P14s AMD Gen2

WiFi: Intel Wifi 6 AX210 non vPro --> support at Kernel 5.10+

OS: dual boot with win 10 + 20.04.2 LTS Ubuntu Mate, Kernel 5.11.0.27

Bluetooth still works, WiFi stops working - not even in the network list - after sudo update&upgrade.

Any recommendations?

I just switched the WiFi card to Intel because the original one (RTL8852AE 11ax) didn't work...

```
ThinkPad-P14s-Gen-2a:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl    
[3.191724] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)    
[3.201020] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver    
[3.201036] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28    
[3.201344] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm                           
[3.287251] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420    
[3.447988] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670    
[3.550190] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!    
[3.550200] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110    
[3.550209] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1    
[3.754235] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway    
[3.766816] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555  added the code, sorry i am new here and tried the last 20 minutes to format the code, with no luck.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this offer a solution?https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: Please also show us: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep -i version` and also: `ls /usr/lib/firmware | grep -i pnvm`

Comment: No change after windows energy change
Ćode:
`ThinkPad-P14s-Gen-2a:~$ sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep -i version
Version: 1.187.16`

Comment: And how about the other command?

Comment: @chili555 sorry i overlooked it..

`-ThinkPad-P14s-Gen-2a:~$ ls /usr/lib/firmware | grep -i pnvm
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm`

Comment: On my 18.04.6, I upgraded the kernel to 5.13.19 and copied the driver from Intel website to /lib/firmware. It worked like a charm after that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> [3.447988] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
> [3.550190] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
> [3.550200] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110

This is the subject of a well-known bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13

Let's try the suggested fix. From the terminal:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

**EDIT**: It appears that periodic updates to the package *linux-firmware* will install a new version of the offending file iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm and so this process will need to be repeated.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

After your suggested fix in the terminal and a reboot, my WiFi was working again :D.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour This will help the searchers with the same issue find the solution.

Comment: sure, i just did.
Thanks again with this fast solution, much faster than from Intel or Lenovo!
Great expirience with this community :).
Have a nice day and wonderful weekend!

Comment: worked like a charm in dell inspiron 7760 with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thank you!  Worked on Asusrock mobo running Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.11

Comment: FYI I needed to do the solution again after a software update -- wifi adapter was not found again.

Comment: @Hammurabi Thanks and please see my edit above.

Comment: Worked on my ThinkPad P15S Gen 2 running Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.11

Comment: This worked on a new install of Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.11.0-41, on a Dell Precision-7560.

Comment: Genius. wasted almost half day figuring it out. This solution fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks! worked for Thinkpad t14 gen3 (WiFi disappeared after update)