# Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210 on Live Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, live-usb, iwlwifi, firmware

on my notebook, I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and after fixing the WiFi issue that persists with the **Intel Wi-Fi AX210** (according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1360291/1548845)), everything works fine on the network side.

However, I would also like to have a USB stick with **live Ubuntu**, in case anything with my system goes wrong and I need to recover something.
There could be situations where I don‘t have ethernet access while requiring the live Ubuntu, so I would like to have Wifi in the live Ubuntu as well.
Problem is that the fix described in the answer I linked requires to reboot which resets all changes to `/lib/firmware`.

I also tried to set up a live Ubuntu with persistent storage following [these instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) but `/lib/firmware` does not show in the persistent partition…

**Any ideas that might help me get a Live Ubuntu 20.04 USB-Stick with working Intel Wi-Fi AX210?**

- System:

  - Lenovo ThinkPad T15g Gen. 2
- OS:

  - Ubuntu 20.04.1
- Kernel:

  - 5.11.0-41-generic
- Wi-Fi Card:

  - Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210