# Intel wifi 6 AX210 driver issue

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, intel, iwlwifi

My Intel Wifi 6 AX210 card is not detected on my fresh Ubuntu Mate installation.

Here is the dmesg output:

```
[    3.341328] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.349932] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.349945] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    3.350218] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.369931] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    3.538721] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[    3.641027] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    3.641033] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.641036] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[    3.845149] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway
[    3.857218] iwlwifi 0000:92:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

My kernel version is:

```
Linux Precision-7560 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea to correct this?
Linux Kernel from 5.10 may support this Wifi card : https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

Thanks.

Comment: No reason to have duplicate Q&A's with exactly the same solution. [Intel Wifi 6 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For 20.04 (focal fossa)

This is a [well-known bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13) #212371

Let's try the suggested fix:

1. Open a terminal by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> .
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak
   ```
3. Reboot to reload the drivers.

**EDIT**: It appears that periodic updates to the package `linux-firmware` will install a new version of the offending file `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` and so this process will need to be repeated.

Good Luck!

---

Alternatively, installing a newer kernel will fix this issue.  In the bug report, users have specifically mentioned kernel `5.16` (for 20.04 only). Here are step by step instructions to install it.

1. Change the working directory  to `~/Downloads` :

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
2. Download the kernel's `.deb` files:

   ```
   wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.0-051600_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_all.deb
   wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb
   wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb
   wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16/amd64/linux-modules-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Install the `.deb` files:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
4. Satisfy the dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt -f install
   ```

That's it! 
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I have uploaded to 5.13 kernel and it works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer.

Comment: I've tried both solutions, neither work. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 tried and reversed both the kernel update and the pnvm rename. Oddly if I unplug the USB_INT connection, WiFi works, but no Bluetooth.  Plug USB_INT in, Bluetooth works, but not WiFi.

Comment: @Jim Unfortunately, this answer is specific to Ubuntu 20.04. I wouldn't recommend trying this on newer releases (I'll edit the answer to mention this detail). I'd recommend, you ask a new question Nd add all the necessary details.

Comment: @Error404 Yep, I recognize that - however it seemed like this was more of a kernel issue vs distribution version issue; so I thought worth a try.