# Bluetooth and WiFi AX210 not working at same time

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, bluetooth, iwlwifi

I installed a Intel AX210 pcie card into my Dell 7850, expecting to have it work after seeing reviews say "it just works" in Ubuntu.

However this is not the case for me.  It seems I can either have WiFi or Bluetooth working, but not both at the same time. If I unplug the USB_INT power cable for the PCIe card, this disabled Bluetooth, but WiFi works.  However if I plug USB_INT power in for the PCIe, WiFi stops working, but Bluetooth works perfectly. As seen below, the hardware is seen as a network device and the driver says loaded, however

I've seen the solution here: [Intel wifi 6 AX210 driver issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388335/intel-wifi-6-ax210-driver-issue), however my variation is that I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.01 with kernel 5.15.0-57-generic. I've tried both solutions proposed (renaming the `.pnvm` file or using the 5.16 kernel and rebooting) as well as using the latest firmware linux-kernel. No solution posted seems to work.

Here's errors I see in dmesg:

```
[   37.195826] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'd0i3_disable' ignored
[   37.195832] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'lar_disable' ignored
[   37.196754] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
[   37.686674] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   37.686761] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.63.2.2
[   37.687736] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   41.622532] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   42.650074] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x7023, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   42.650226] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047f600
[   42.650332] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   42.650403] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   42.650527] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[   42.650648] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   42.650750] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   42.650835] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   42.650920] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   42.651002] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   42.651087] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   42.651171] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   42.651245] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   42.651319] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   42.651393] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   42.651474] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   42.651551] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   42.651626] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   42.651704] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   42.651782] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   42.651871] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   42.651958] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   42.652046] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   42.652125] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   42.652206] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   42.652278] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   42.652349] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   42.652420] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   42.652491] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   42.652562] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   42.652633] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   42.652713] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   42.652791] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   42.652871] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   42.652951] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   42.653030] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   42.653113] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   42.653193] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   42.653271] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   42.653396] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   42.653477] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   42.653574] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   42.653662] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   42.653747] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[   42.653833] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   42.653920] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   42.654030] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x0000000C | umac data1
[   42.654110] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00040000 | umac data2
[   42.654189] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   42.654268] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[   42.654346] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[   42.654425] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00011330 | frame pointer
[   42.654508] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xC0887F34 | stack pointer
[   42.654590] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   42.654671] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   42.654782] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   42.654849] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   42.654959] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00007023 | IML/ROM data1
[   42.655054] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   42.655153] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   42.655223] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   42.655305] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00440005 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   42.655392] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   42.655481] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   42.655563] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   42.655653] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   42.655735] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   42.655815] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   42.655895] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   42.655981] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   42.656068] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   42.656174] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   42.656279] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   42.656351] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   43.731525] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   43.744133] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: retry init count 0
[   43.744565] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   44.762068] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x7022, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   44.762220] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047f600
[   44.762343] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   44.762445] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   44.762569] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[   44.762750] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   44.762898] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   44.763011] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   44.763088] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   44.763153] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   44.763219] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   44.763285] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   44.763343] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   44.763401] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   44.763459] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   44.763523] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   44.763583] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   44.763641] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   44.763702] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   44.763763] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   44.763834] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   44.763904] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   44.763974] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   44.764037] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   44.764102] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   44.764159] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   44.764216] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   44.764273] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   44.764330] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   44.764387] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   44.764444] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   44.764508] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   44.764570] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   44.764634] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   44.764698] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   44.764761] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   44.764827] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   44.764892] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   44.764953] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   44.765062] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   44.765127] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   44.765205] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   44.765276] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   44.765344] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[   44.765412] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   44.765483] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   44.765553] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x0000000C | umac data1
[   44.765616] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00040000 | umac data2
[   44.765679] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   44.765741] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[   44.765804] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[   44.765867] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00011331 | frame pointer
[   44.765958] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xC0887F34 | stack pointer
[   44.766026] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   44.766093] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   44.766187] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   44.766241] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   44.766340] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00007022 | IML/ROM data1
[   44.766435] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   44.770385] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   44.774463] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   44.778424] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00440005 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   44.781350] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   44.783840] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   44.786311] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   44.788757] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   44.790785] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   44.792546] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   44.794271] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   44.796002] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   44.797726] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   44.799482] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   44.800787] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   44.802039] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   45.876072] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   45.888728] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: retry init count 1
[   45.889646] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   46.906061] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x7023, CPU2 Status: 0xb03
[   46.906105] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8047f600
[   46.906140] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x0
[   46.906148] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   46.906269] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
[   46.906277] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   46.906285] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status0
[   46.906291] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   46.906296] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[   46.906302] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[   46.906307] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[   46.906313] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   46.906318] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[   46.906323] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   46.906329] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   46.906334] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf low
[   46.906339] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   46.906345] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   46.906350] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp2
[   46.906355] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[   46.906361] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version major
[   46.906366] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode version minor
[   46.906372] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | hw version
[   46.906377] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | board version
[   46.906383] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[   46.906388] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr0
[   46.906393] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   46.906398] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr2
[   46.906403] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr3
[   46.906409] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   46.906414] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   46.906419] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   46.906425] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   46.906430] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   46.906436] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   46.906441] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   46.906446] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   46.906452] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   46.906457] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | flow_handler
[   46.906508] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   46.906513] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
[   46.906521] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x201013F2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   46.906528] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   46.906533] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x8045DFC6 | umac branchlink2
[   46.906539] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[   46.906545] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   46.906550] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x0000000C | umac data1
[   46.906556] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00040000 | umac data2
[   46.906561] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   46.906567] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000042 | umac major
[   46.906573] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xF1C864E0 | umac minor
[   46.906578] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00011330 | frame pointer
[   46.906584] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0xC0887F34 | stack pointer
[   46.906590] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[   46.906595] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   46.906628] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   46.906633] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   46.906667] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00007023 | IML/ROM data1
[   46.906700] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   46.906730] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   46.906749] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   46.906768] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00440005 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   46.906789] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   46.906809] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   46.906828] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   46.906848] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   46.906868] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   46.906887] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   46.906907] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   46.906928] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   46.906950] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   46.906972] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   46.906992] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   46.906999] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[   47.973605] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   47.986047] iwlwifi 0000:17:00.0: retry init count 2
```

Then `lspci -nnk` yields:

```
0000:17:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

And I've also tried the suggestions here https://gist.github.com/mixxen/339846df6f316416336d038090a3c848#file-intel-ax200-drivers-ubuntu-L6 and added the following options per that advice to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=0 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
options iwlwifi d0i3_disable=1
options iwlwifi uapsd_disable=1
options iwlwifi lar_disable=1
```

And lastly `lshw -C network` yields:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (3) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 09
       serial: 54:bf:64:8f:66:29
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-57-generic duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=192.168.108.230 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:73 memory:90380000-9039ffff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:17:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:85 memory:94000000-94003fff
```

I don't have Windows 10 installed as a dual boot (however Windows 10 was installed at some previous point in time). I don't know if Fast Boot was enabled, however I don't see any option for that within the Bios.  I did disable Secure Boot (when I tried kernel v5.16).

Not sure where to go next.  Thanks in advance!