# I can find my device on lspci but not on nmcli

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I had some network issues
I have a computer with dual boot with windows and Linux
The windows computer is working fine but when I get into Linux, no WiFi or network is working
I try to use nmcli and it showing just
Device lo
Type lookback
State unmanaged
And when I use the command lspci I would see my device
It is the intel corporation wi-fi 6 ax210
Also with slusb I can see the Bluetooth part of it.
I put a usb dongle for WiFi
Ralink technology, corp. mt7601u wireless adapter
Every time I try with apt it will tell me failed to fetch and the Ubuntu link
I am super new at this and I’m thinking about installing Ubuntu again
The only thing I don’t want is to loose the dual boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel wifi 6 AX210 driver issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388335/intel-wifi-6-ax210-driver-issue)

Comment: Basic starting point is what Ubuntu product & release you're using, as this allows us to provide more specific advice, instead of *generic* advice that will work on most Ubuntu products/releases. Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice, with your default set by your installation media; we don't yet know what product/release you actually installed, thus won't know if you're using an *older* or *newer* kernel stack; or something else.

Comment: Hello the release is the 22.04 and the description when lsb_release is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `uname -r; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; sudo dmesg|grep iwl`