# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 Driver doesn't work after update

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

This issue returned after updating Ubuntu and it can't be fixed by the working solution of renaming/removing pnvm file anymore as mentioned in following solutions. How to fix it now?

[Intel Wifi 6 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update)

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Log is here https://pastebin.com/SBhH0mh5

```
gamepc:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/firmware | grep pnvm
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   41804 Mar 10 07:05 iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
```

Renaming/deleting iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm doesn't solve the issue.

```
$ lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               372736  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              888832  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211 

$ inxi -n
Network:   Device-1: Intel driver: igc 
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: d8:bb:c1:8a:56:3c 
           Device-2: Intel driver: iwlwifi 

gamepc:~$ uname -r
5.13.0-39-generic

gamepc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

gamepc:~$ sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep -i version
Version: 1.187.29

gamepc:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: d8:bb:c1:8a:56:3c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=1079:8770 ip=192.168.0.56 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:51b00000-51bfffff memory:51c00000-51c03fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:52000000-52003fff

$ dkms status
backport-iwlwifi, 8324: added
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Hello. Have you been doing the system updates as prompted by the system on a regular basis or running update and upgrade. My Ubuntu 20.04 uname -r is 5.4.0-107-generic
Yours is quite a bit lower.

Comment: I can't remember what I did but it seems it's set to auto update and when I rebooted system wifi stopped working. I might have done update when prompted.

Comment: Try installing `dkms` and `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`. Report back. If it works, I'll write a formal answer for you. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema backport-iwlwifi-dkms is already the newest version (8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4).

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status`. There's a newer version of backport-iwlwifi-dkms, but it's for 21.10, so I don't know if it'll work with 20.04, but you can try it. https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/backport-iwlwifi-dkms

Comment: @heynnema I've updated my question with `dkms status`

Comment: The backport-iwlwifi shows as "added", but not "installed". So it's not working. First confirm that Secure Boot is disabled in your BIOS. Then do `sudo dkms build backport-iwlwifi/8324` and report back.

Comment: @heynnema Fast boot was disabled very first time I started to mess with Intel WiFi.  $ sudo dkms build backport-iwlwifi/8324
Error!  The /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/5.13.0-39-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module backport-iwlwifi includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.

Comment: I was talking about Secure Boot, not Fast Boot. Are you current on your Software Updater? Your kernel may be wrong? Have you manually changed your kernel?

Comment: @heynnema I'm not sure how secure boot etc. will affect when nothing has changed since it was working in 5.11? Updater doesn't show any pending update. No, I haven't manually touched kernel.

Comment: Where did you get your copy of backport-iwlwifi-dkms? Secure Boot needs to be disabled for unsigned kernel modules, or they won't build/run. If you know how, grep the source code for "BUILD_EXCLUSIVE" and let's see where it's tripping up. You'll probably find it in the makefile. The source is in /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8324 (or something similar).

Comment: OK, I found it. Let me put together an answer on how to modify it to work with your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there is a later version of the firmware is available. I also suspect that your -63 version may be corrupted. Let's download fresh copies.

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
```

Reboot and show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZuhRa7ru  looks like still same error. I've downloaded firmware as you suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

We have to modify your copy of backport-iwlwifi-dkms (8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4) to work with your newer kernel (5.13.0-39-generic). This newer kernel got installed with a recent Software Update.

**Note**: **Secure Boot** must be disabled in your BIOS.

This `dkms status` output shows us that backport-iwlwifi was never working on your system:

```
backport-iwlwifi, 8324: added
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
```

So we have to modify it.

`sudo -H gedit /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8324/dkms.conf`

At the top of the file you'll see:

```
PACKAGE_NAME="backport-iwlwifi"
PACKAGE_VERSION="8324"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
BUILD_EXCLUSIVE_KERNEL="^((5\.[0-3]($|[.-]))|(4\.))"
```

The **BUILD_EXCLUSIVE_KERNEL** limits it's use to an earlier kernel from 20.04.

Comment out this line by placing a "#" at the front of that line:

```
#BUILD_EXCLUSIVE_KERNEL="^((5\.[0-3]($|[.-]))|(4\.))"
```

Save the file. Then do:

`sudo dkms build backport-iwlwifi/8324`

**Note**: If the `build` fails, it'll probably be because you're missing a linux header file. Go ahead and install the missing file, and redo the `build` command.

`sudo dkms install backport-iwlwifi/8324`

`dkms status` should now show:

```
backport-iwlwifi, 8324, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Reboot and retest your wireless.

**Note**: If it's still not working, we'll have to get the newer backport-iwlwifi-dkms (9340-0ubuntu4) at https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/backport-iwlwifi-dkms.

`dkms status` should now show:

```
backport-iwlwifi, 9340, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Update #1:**

```
MSI Z690 Carbon WIFI DDR5: ATX w/USB3.2, 5x M.2
BIOS version 1.21
CPU Intel® Core™ i9-12900K
```

There's a BIOS update for your i9 at https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-Z690-CARBON-WIFI/support.

**Note**: confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard

**Note**: do backups before updating the BIOS

Update the BIOS. Retest wifi. Report back.

**Update #2:**

We tried with a modified backport-iwlwifi-dkms from focal, and a standard impish version with no luck. We tried -67 ucode with no luck.

BIOS has been updated to support i9 processor.

Kernel 5.13.0-37-generic, wifi doesn't work.

Kernel 5.13.0-39-generic, wifi doesn't work.

Kernel 5.11.0-27-generic, wifi works fine.

Run with kernel 5.11.0-27-generic until a kernel > -39 is released, and then retest wifi.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I got this error on build $ sudo dkms build backport-iwlwifi/8324

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j24 KLIB=/lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: Installing missing file also gives error: $ sudo dkms install backport-iwlwifi/8324

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j24 KLIB=/lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/backport-iwlwifi-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: @Raymond What does /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/build/make.log show?

Comment: @Raymond Delete /var/crash/backport-iwlwifi-dkms.0.crash

Comment: I've deleted the make log and ran the commands again but still same error. Here is the log you requested https://pastebin.com/g96dJczM

Comment: @Raymond It looks like the newer kernel will require the newer backport-iwlwifi-dkms that I reference in my answer. No mods should be required. Purge the current backport-iwlwifi-dkms before installing the newer version. Then do the dkms add/build/install using the new 9340 version number.

Comment: So shall I uncomment the line in /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8324/dkms.conf and then install backport?

Comment: @Raymond No need. Just purge the older backport-iwlwifi-dkms before installing the newer version. `dkms status` should not show the backport after the purge.

Comment: Sorry can't seem to find out how to install this specific version of backport? Did google search but can't figure it out, let me know command please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135242/discussion-between-heynnema-and-raymond).

Comment: @Raymond Try this. Make yourself a Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB (with kernel 5.15) and see if wifi works then. Report back.

Comment: @Raymond They're released a new kernel. Run your Software Updater to install it. Reboot and retest. Report back.

Comment: Software updater didn't show any updates, installed 5.17.3 manually via CLI and it fucks up nVidia driver. Another day to waste to figure out nvidia driver insgtallation now. Not sure if it is supported on 5.17.3.

Comment: @Raymond I don't think that 5.17.3 and Nvidia have a love affair yet. Did you ever try the Ubuntu Live 22.04 beta that I recommended on Apr 9?

Comment: @heynnemma No I didn't it's too much work for me. I just want to get WiFi +nVidia working.

Comment: @Raymond The Ubuntu Live 22.04 beta would be to see if kernel 5.15 solved the wifi problem. Take about 15 minutes to do.

Comment: @Raymond Status please...

Comment: I did upgrade but it didn't work and it fucked up my GPU driver. So I'm without GPU and WiFi.

Comment: @Raymond Are you on kernel 5.17.3? You have Nvidia, yes? One problem at a time... boot to the 5.11.0-27-generic kernel and reinstall Nvidia if required, and then purge the 5.17.3 kernel, as it didn't solve anything. Your GPU and wifi should be working again.

Comment: @Raymond Did we ever get backport-iwlwifi version 9340 installed and running on your system with the -37 and -39 kernels?