# How to enable Wifi on the GPD Pocket 3 on (K)Ubuntu 22.04, Wi-Fi 6 AX210?

Tags: networking, kubuntu

Today I received my GPD Pocket 3. It came preinstalled with Windows 11. The device looks great. I Installed Kubuntu 22.04 in dual boot (It is the first time, I have a dual boot device since winXP, but this form factor often has compatibility issues with linux, so I kept Windows as a backup).

Wifi is not working (yet), and this is where I would appreciate your help.

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:ae:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       description: Network controller
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:88400000-88403fff

lsmod | grep iwlwifi 

iwlwifi               446464  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              962560  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211

sudo iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp175s0  no wireless extensions.
```

The device does not show up in rfkill. Wifi does work in Windows 11, after installing the driver from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19351/windows-10-and-windows-11-wi-fi-drivers-for-intel-wireless-adapters.html).

Running

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak
```

as suggested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update) answer, does not change anything. I would prefer not to change the kernel.

Comment: Please add the following commands output to your original post: `sudo journalctl -b -k  | grep firmware` and maybe ' uname  -v` (I don't know which kernel Kubuntu 22 is using; 5.17 ?) and `modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware`. It is very possible that you have to install firmware for your card.  Did you install the iwlwifi package?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @abu_bua Thank you. Strangely after updating on windows 11, I got wifi on Ubuntu too...Is this logical?

Comment: @chili Thank you. Strangely the problem went away after updating on windows...Any ideas why?

Comment: Is Fast Boot a possible issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @chili555 might be, will search that feature on windows on the WE and see. I really have not used windows on bare metal for some time now. My year of the linux desktop was 2007...

Comment: Since Windows 8 the Fast Startup feature has been creating many issues when dual-booting, reason why I often say that disabling in the context of dual-booting is a MUST.