# `nmcli d wifi list` returns nothing

Tags: networking, 20.04

I've 2 Ubuntu machines, U1 + U2.

U1 works fine. Wireless on `U2` is not working. I switched Wi-Fi off and on and rebooted. I still don't see Wi-Fi access points.

NB: Running different versions.

---

U1:

```
me@me-Latitude-3510:~$ nmcli d wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  B>
        08:31:8B:36:28:1B  --                Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  69      ▂>
        08:31:8B:36:28:17  HUAWEI-B535-2817  Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  64      ▂>
        08:31:8B:36:28:1E  --                Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  62      ▂>
        90:02:18:3D:D2:EE  SKY1FNIN          Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  47      ▂>
*       08:31:8B:36:28:1C  HUAWEI-B535-2817  Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  44      ▂>
        40:A5:EF:24:A7:82  House Bridge      Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  39      ▂>
        90:02:18:85:6D:9C  SKY1FNIN          Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  32      ▂>
        6C:A0:B4:61:D7:4A  SKY1FNIN          Infra  6     260 Mbit/s  29      ▂>
        90:02:18:3D:D2:EB  SKY1FNIN          Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  25      ▂>
        18:82:8C:9D:7B:5B  EE-Hub-J2uH       Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  19      ▂>
me@me-Latitude-3510:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

[wireless-info.txt](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/xJvryZy2TN/)

---

U2:

```
me@me:~$ nmcli d wifi list
me@me:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

me@me:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for me: 
[    2.938668] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.943049] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.943065] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    2.943386] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.028849] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    3.194473] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[    3.297648] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    3.297670] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.297684] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[    3.505767] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway
[    3.517735] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

[wireless-info.txt](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/DhB3cMj7Ds/)

Comment: Please refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/167115) and follow the instructions to provide the information needed to troubleshoot the issue, thanks.

Comment: "iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110" May we see a paste of: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Is this a dual boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: Hi @chili555. It is, but I didn't complete the Windows setup. So just Pre-installation env. Check post

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update/1360291#1360291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal, run:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak
```

Then Reboot.

[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1360291/1383985)

---

Then, to confirm, I ran:

```
me@me:~$ nmcli d wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  B>
        08:31:8B:36:28:17  HUAWEI-B535-2817  Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  100     ▂>
        08:31:8B:36:28:1C  HUAWEI-B535-2817  Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  100     ▂>
        40:A5:EF:24:A7:82  House Bridge      Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  25      ▂>
        6C:A0:B4:61:D7:4A  SKY1FNIN          Infra  1     260 Mbit/s  22      ▂>
        90:02:18:3D:D2:EB  SKY1FNIN          Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  20      ▂>
        08:31:8B:36:28:1E  --                Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  14      ▂>
```